# spark streaming print() method

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

According to Sparks documentation on [output transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams)

> **print()**:  Prints the first ten elements of every batch of data in a DStream on the driver node running the streaming application. This
>   is useful for development and debugging.

according to the [cluster overview documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html):

> Spark applications run as independent sets of processes on a cluster,
>   coordinated by the SparkContext object in your main program (called
>   the driver program).

My question is is the driver == master?

i.e. does print prints at the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is, is the driver == master?

No. The driver is the process where you initialize your `SparkContext`. It will live where you tell it to. For example, if you run your job using `local[*]` which works locally, the driver is initialized locally on your machine. If you run spark in "client mode" on the default Standalone resource manager, it will start the driver from the location submitting the job. If you use "cluster mode", the driver will be dispatched to one of the Worker nodes in the cluster.

A master is a standalone process which is responsible for managing the cluster. It knows which workers it's managing, and it is his job to give you sufficient resources to run your driver such that you can utilize the cluster.

When you use `DStream.print`, the data will be send to whichever location is running your driver. If you started your driver from a machine that also happens to be the machine running your master process, then that is the machine which will receive the data and print the output.

Answer (score 2):

Master is a resource manager. It doesn't participate directly in data processing and it not a part of the application.

`print` is executed on the driver which is the entry point of your application.

Comment: but if you have cluster of 1 master & 3 workers? where it will print?

Comment: Neither. It will output on the driver node (which in cluster mode can be a worker machine).